# Restore deleted (?) Google OAuth client app for production system

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-client, google-oauth

we are getting a 401 Error from Google API:

```
401. That’s an error.
Error: deleted_client

The OAuth client was deleted.
```

It seems that the Google-OAuth-API Client was deleted. Maybe on firebase? Whould be really strange when we delete a firebase project that it is also deleted on Google API...

Is there any way to restore this?!

Thanks a lot for your help!

Best

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For everyone who has this problem too. Found the solution:

> Project owners can restore a deleted project within the 30-day
>   recovery period that starts when the project is shut down. Restoring a
>   project returns it to the state it was in before it was shut down.
>   Cloud Storage resources are deleted before the 30-day period ends, and
>   may not be fully recoverable.
>
> Some services might need to be restarted manually. For more
>   information, see Restarting Google Cloud Platform Services.
>
> To restore a project:
>
> Go to the Manage Resources page in the Google Cloud Platform Console.
>
> In the Organization drop-down in the upper left, select your
>   organization.
>
> Below the list of projects, click Resources pending deletion.
>
> Check the box for the project you want to restore, then click Restore.
>   In the dialog that appears, confirm that you want to restore the
>   project.

Source: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787?hl=en

Comment: This doesn't allow you to undelete a client, just the entire project.

Comment: If anyone has reached this page because they've gotten the `401: deleted_client` error for a Google Apps Script project, I've posted a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66016751/google-apps-script-error-401-deleted-client-the-oauth-client-was-deleted-all/70352637#70352637).

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible currently by contacting Google Cloud support, and even then it's not guaranteed they can do it.  I just went through the process.  The support engineer did mention that they're working to build out "undo-delete" as a feature but they didn't have any dates to share.