# Android: The OAuth client was deleted

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm using firebase authentication, after I used android google sign in for a while.

I'm getting this error:

```
401. That’s an error.

Error: deleted_client

The OAuth client was deleted.
```

the weird thing, is that I'm getting this error for some emails, and no problem for other??

I rechecked the client id.

do I have to delete the project and create new one?

Comment: Check this out if it helps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39053115/6157920

Comment: @kukroid I don't want to restore the project, I created new one, But it seems that some emails keep using the old client id !!